# Bubbling Up Nested-transaction Failures with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a method in a service object that composes operations that should be wrapped in a transaction. Some of these operations are also wrapped in transactions. For example:

```
class PostCreator
   def create
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        post.do_this
        post.do_that
        user.do_more(post, other_stuff)
      end
   end
 end

 def Post
   def do_this
     transaction do; ...; end
   end
 end
```

I need any nested failures to bubble up all the way to the top, but I'm not sure how to make that happen, and the ActiveRecord docs on [nested transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#label-Nested+transactions) don't seem to offer a solution. From the docs:

```
# Standard nesting

User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  User.transaction do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback    #  This won't bubble up:
                                    #  _Both_ users will still be created.
  end
end

# Nesting with `requires_new: true` on the nested transaction

User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  User.transaction(requires_new: true) do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback    #  This won't bubble up either
                                    #  "Kotori" will still be created.
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a great question. I often see the situation where a method is sometimes called by itself, so its contents are wrapped in a transaction, but is sometimes is called from inside another transaction. I think it would be better if ActiveRecord bubbled errors up by default when :requires_new is not enabled (since the nested block is part of the parent transaction).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413599/why-does-rails-ignore-a-rollback-in-a-pseudonested-transaction/22483702#comment40757874_22483702

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's how you could get failures in your nested transactions to bubble up:

```
User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless User.transaction(requires_new: true) do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Basically, you have to raise an error in your top-level transaction for it to rollback too. To do that, you raise an error if the nested transaction returns a falsey value(nil) or a truthy value.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 16):

Another easier approach, you can raise an CustomError < StandardError. Unlike ActiveRecord::Rollback, Error will bubble up through parent transactions. You can handle it wherever required. All other inner transactions will be rolled back.

Try the below template.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transacton do
    ActiveRecord::Base.transacton do
        raise StandardError.new
    end
end
```

Comment: This is way easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a custom error is always a good option in case of nested transactions. Please find more detail on [nested-transations-in-rails](http://geekdirt.com/blog/nested-transations-in-rails/) .

Comment: If you link to your own blog or something like that, you need to disclose that. A simple *"my"* is sufficient. Also, this does look a bit thin. Can you give a concrete example to go with that suggestion?