# Why does Rails ignore a Rollback in a (pseudo)nested transaction?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

As per the docs [ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), a non-new nested transaction will ignore a Rollback. From the docs:

```
User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  User.transaction do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

The `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` is ignored because it is in a child transaction (or rather, it is still within the parent transaction and not its own). I do not understand why the Rollback call would be ignored by both? I can see that since the child 'transaction' isn't really a transaction, that it would not roll back the 'Nemu' block, but why does it not trigger a rollback for the parent? Does the child transaction hide the rollback somehow?

In other words, why is it that there appears to be no way to roll back a parent transaction from within a nested child?

Comment: See this question for an example of how to work around this behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926873/bubbling-up-nested-transaction-failures-with-activerecord

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually this is exactly how **Nested Transactions** was designed for. I quote from oracle docs:

> A nested transaction is used to provide a transactional guarantee for a subset of operations performed within the scope of a larger transaction.  Doing this allows you to commit and abort the subset of
>   operations independently of the larger transaction.

So, a child transaction in a regular **nested transaction** has no say regarding how him or the other children or parent (*larger transaction*) could behave, other than changing mutual data or failing for an exception.

But you can grant him (*child transaction*) a very limited voting chance on his destiny by utilizing the `sub-transaction` feature as stated at rails [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) by passing `requires_new: true`

```
User.transaction do
  User.create(username: 'Kotori')
  User.transaction(requires_new: true) do
    User.create(username: 'Nemu')
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Which as the docs say: only creates 'Kotori'. since the powerful 'Nemu' child chose to die silently.

More details about **Nested transaction rules** ([oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/gsg_xml_txn/java/nestedtxn.html))

**Update:**

To better understand why rails `nested transactions` works this way, you need to know a bit more about how nested transactions works in DB level, I quote from [rails api docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/transaction):

> Most databases don’t support true nested transactions ...In order to
>   get around this problem, #transaction will emulate the effect of
>   nested transactions, by using savepoints:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/savepoint.html

Ok, then the docs describes the behavior of a `nested transaction` in the two mentioned cases as follows:

In case of a nested call, [#transaction](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/transaction) will behave as follows:

- The block will be run without doing anything. All database statements that happen within the block are effectively appended to the already open database transaction.
- However, if :requires_new is set, the block will be wrapped in a database savepoint acting as a sub-transaction.

I imagine *careful, only imagine* that:

**option(1)** (**without** requires_new) is there in case you used a DBMS that fully supports `nested transactions` or you are happy with the "fake" behavior of `nested_attributes`

while **option(2)** is to support the `savepoint` workaround if you don't.

Comment: But why require using `require_new` at all, if the alternative is that a Rollback does *nothing* -- by default.

Comment: @Nimir, your update doesn't sound right to me. The docs imply that transactions without `requires_new` would behave the same regardless of whether or not the DBMS supports nested transactions. It sounds like DBMS support for nested transactions merely changes how ActiveRecord implements the `requires_new` case. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Nimir - I understand that it would be weird for a nested `transaction{}` to let exceptions bubble up if a nested `transaction(requires_new: true){}` did not. But why can't a `transaction` *always* let exceptions bubble up, whether nested or not? (If you wanted the nested transaction to fail and the parent transaction to succeed, you could just catch the exception.)

Comment: I still don't get why the behavior of `requires_new: true` isn't the default for nested transactions. Why would I ever not want to use it?

Answer (score 12):

This is because of an interaction with how `transaction do` blocks specifically handle `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exceptions that are raised within those blocks and how Rails joins together nested `transaction do` blocks by default.

1. Rails `transaction do` blocks have slightly different behaviors depending on the type of exception raised within them:

- When `ActiveRecord::Rollback` exceptions are raised within a `transaction do` block, those exceptions are rescued by the `transaction do` block and do *not* bubble up farther.
- All other kinds of exceptions are rescued *and re-raised* by a `transaction do` block and *do* continue to bubble up beyond that block.

2. By default, Rails "joins" nested transactions together. This means that a transaction will only be aborted when the most-exterior transaction has an exception bubble up through it.

Together, these two behaviors mean that when a `ActiveRecord::Rollback` is raised within a nested transaction, it is rescued by the interior `transaction do` block and does *not* re-raise; the exterior `transaction do` block, because it does not receive the exception, completes successfully.

To stress, if you raise any exception *other* than an `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, it will continue to bubble up through multiple `transaction do` blocks and the exterior transaction will abort as expected.

As mentioned elsewhere, you can force Rails' nested transactions to not "join" their parent with `transaction(requires_new: true) do`; as well as force parent transactions not to be joined by children with `transaction(joinable: false) do`. It's been [recommended](https://makandracards.com/makandra/42885-nested-activerecord-transaction-pitfalls) to always use both `transaction(joinable: false, requires_new: true) do`

Comment: Thank you! This is the most clear and explanatory answer about how exceptions & tx behave and for what one would use `joinable`.