# Nested transactions and rollbacks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is in regards to using nested transactions in rails with ActiveRecord.

What I need to do is make sure both saves are successful else rollback if ether fail and return true or false based on the success.

Hers is the code

```
Card.transaction do
    Transaction.transaction do
        @card_saved = card.save
        @transaction_saved = self.save
     end
     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end

if @transaction_saved and @card_saved
    return true
end
return false
```

Do I need to add a rollback in the inner block as well or will the outer catch both?

Comment: you can find everything you need about transactions here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Comment: You'll find a bubbling up rollback solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926873/bubbling-up-nested-transaction-failures-with-activerecord